# PYTHON_EGG_CACHE on Kivy-ios

Tags: python, ios, macos, kivy, kivymd

Looking for a little help solving this issue, I have Kivy-ios setup on my MacBook Pro (Intel) wrote a simple kivymd code to make sure everything was installed properly. On the IPhone simulator app runs fine, but when trying to run it on my IPhone 11 Pro running iOS 14.6 I get this error.

[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FD3FBCB4-48DD-42D6-BB45-5C4A5B9BB459/.cache'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FD3FBCB4-48DD-42D6-BB45-5C4A5B9BB459/.cache/Python-Eggs

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?
You can change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE
environment variable to point to an accessible directory.

2021-07-16 16:06:41.776811-0400 iosapp[15494:1173515] Application quit abnormally!
2021-07-16 16:06:41.793881-0400 iosapp[15494:1173515] Leaving

Even tried setting the os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = 'path/to/directory' but still get the exact same error except with the path I assigned to the environment.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton, MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard, MDSeparator
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel


class IOSTest(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        box = MDCard(orientation='vertical', size_hint=(None,None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        lab = MDLabel(text='Hello ios', halign='center')
        box.add_widget(lab)
    
        return box
    
IOSTest().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a pillow issue, I think. If you already have an egg file (like Pillow-6.x.x-py3.x-macosx-11.2-x86_64.egg), you can right click and extract the contents, then copy and paste its PIL folder to kivy-ios/dist/root/python3/lib/python3.x/site-packages/ folder. Then the issue might be solved. Have a good luck!